# How to retrieve related data from deeply nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have deeply nested resources below:

```
    resources :venues, shallow: true do
        #Halls
        get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
        get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
        get "structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
        resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
        resources :halls do
            resources :webcasts
            resources :booths do
                resources :chats
            end
        end
    end
```

I want to retrieve all `events` rows that belong to a certain user using `activerecord`

I tried below but this doesn't seem to be generating results that I want which is event data:

```
def all_events
    @events = User.joins(:venues => [:events]).where("venues.user_id" => current_user.id).select("events.*, users.*")
    render json: @events
  end
```

above generates:

```
{
users: [
{
id: 1,
email: "eeee",
title: "Mr",
first_name: "aaaa",
last_name: "cccc",
position: "Web Developer",
work_phone: "123456",
company: "aaasszz",
sign_in_count: 60,
last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
confirmed_at: "2013-10-29T12:26:00.583+11:00",
created_at: "2013-10-29T12:23:25.453+11:00",
roles: [
3
]
},
{
id: 1,
email: "email",
title: "Mr",
first_name: "aaa",
last_name: "bbb",
position: "Web Developer",
work_phone: "123456",
company: "sss",
sign_in_count: 60,
last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
confirmed_at: "2013-10-29T12:26:00.583+11:00",
created_at: "2013-10-29T12:23:25.453+11:00",
roles: [
3
]
}
]
}
```

I want events data in JSON instead...

I'm also using active model serializers.

What is the best approach for this problem?

**Event Model:**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  belongs_to :venue

  validates :name, :start, :finish, presence: true

    has_one :event_image, ->{where(:image_type => UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_EVENT_IMAGE)}, as: :imageable, class_name: 'UploadedFile', dependent: :destroy
    has_one :logo1, ->{where(:image_type => UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_EVENT_LOGO1)}, as: :imageable, class_name: 'UploadedFile', dependent: :destroy
    has_one :logo2, ->{where(:image_type => UploadedFile::IMAGE_TYPE_EVENT_LOGO2)}, as: :imageable, class_name: 'UploadedFile', dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_image, :logo1, :logo2, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['assets'].blank? }

end
```

Comment: show your event model code, along with the Events table column names

Comment: @beck03076 I just updated with event model

Comment: so Event belongs to Venue, Venue belongs_to User. User has_many Venues and Venues has_many Events. Your input is the current_user id. So, you want, all the events the belongs_to current_user's venues???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes are not important for the retrieval of the records from the database. The only thing that matters here is the model. You can include related objects with [the `includes` method from ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes). Because you want events in the end, just start the query from the Event model. Here's the simplest solution I can think of:

```
Event.includes(:venue).where(:venues => {:user_id => current_user.id})
```

if you don't need the venue data, just use `joins`:

```
Event.joins(:venue).where(:venues => {:user_id => current_user.id})
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `No route matches {:controller=>"events", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. I think this should work now without any modifications.

Comment: I'm getting `No route matches {:controller=>"events", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with the query, your url seems to be broken. Check your routes and views!

Comment: But you can already check if the query works in `rails console`

Comment: This is my routes `get "events/all_events", :to => "events#all_events"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45922/discussion-between-p11y-and-passionate-developer)